# Knockout checked binding not updating if radio button is deleted

Tags: binding, knockout.js, radio-button

I have a page with a set of radio buttons that is dynamically created by knockout based on the selection of a drop down on the page.  This is all working fine but the problem I have is that the "checked" binding on the radio buttons does not seem to be cleared if the radio button is removed due to a change of the drop down.  This leaves me with a ViewModel with a value for "checked" when in fact nothing on the view is checked (or at least nothing that can be seen).

What I would expect to happen is that once the radio button is removed the checked binding would go back to being null but I can only assume the binding does not get updated if the radio button is removed from the DOM.

You can see this happening on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avbU7/) - basically if you select a radio button and then change the drop down the selected value will still refer to the now removed (and therefore unchecked) radio button.

HTML:

```
<ul data-bind='foreach: availableChildren'>
<li>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="children" data-bind="checked: $root.selectedChild, value: id" /><span data-bind="text: name"></span>

    </label>
</li>
```

ViewModel:

```
var ViewModel = function (settings) {

var availableParents = ko.observableArray(settings.parents),
    selectedParent = ko.observable(),

    availableChildren = ko.computed(function () {
        if (!selectedParent()) {
            return null;
        }
        return selectedParent().children;
    }),
    selectedChild = ko.observable();

return {
    availableParents: availableParents,
    selectedParent: selectedParent,
    availableChildren: availableChildren,
    selectedChild: selectedChild,
};
};
```

Is there anyway to get this to work as I would expect or is this just something that has been missed from Knockout?

Answer (score 1):

I added this snippet to your viewmodel to get the behaviour you wanted:

```
// create internal computed
ko.computed(function() {
    // add dependency to selectedParent
    var s = selectedParent();
    // reset selectedChild
    selectedChild('');
});
```

Your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/danne567/avbU7/2/

Comment: You should `subscribe` on the `selectedParent` change instead of creating a computed: `selectedParent.subscribe(function() {
    selectedChild('');
});`

Comment: Yes, that makes more sense. Add it as an answer as it's a better solution than mine.

Comment: Yes, both of these solutions seem to work.  I do wonder if it should be necessary though, shouldn't Knockout pick up on this itself?  Also, I'm not sure if this might cause problems later on, especially if something in the viewmodel becomes dependant on both selectedParent and selectedChild.  Still, it works for now so thanks.